# Dialog theme animation issue

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-theme, android-styles, android-dialog

I have create a dialog using `AlertDialog` class. With custom view. I want to set entry and exit animation for it. when I try to do that dialog converts itself to small black background view. How to get animation with  proper view ?? 
[image: Right view]
[image: wrong view after theme set]

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            /*getContext()*/
            new android.support.v7.view.ContextThemeWrapper(getContext(), R.style.StyleDialog));

    View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_email, null);
    builder.setView(view);
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
```

These are the styles

```
<style name="StyleDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/DialogAnimation</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DialogAnimation">
        <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/fadein</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/fadeout</item>
    </style>
```

tried both `android.support.v7.view.ContextThemeWrapper` and `android.view.ContextThemeWrapper` but no difference.

Using `android.app.AlertDialog` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. Just set background(in my case white) for layout which I had not given. Because when we set our own style then it use black background by default and if do not set style then it uses white background by default.

```
android:background="@color/bg_white"
```

For proper width, set first view width to match_parent.

`android:layout_width="match_parent"`